# ri yields "Nothing known about..." though rvm docs exist ('rvm docs open' works)

Tags: ruby, rvm, ri

I've installed Ruby.
I've generated the rvm docs (with `$ rvm docs generate`).
I've closed terminal and re-opened it.

When I enter this:
    $ ri GC
I get this: "Nothing known about GC"

If I enter this:
    $ rvm docs open
It does open the docs on my local drive.
...and I can search for "GC" and see it's page.
file://localhost/Users/mynamehere/.rvm/docs/ruby-2.0.0-p247/rdoc/GC.html

I just can't get the terminal command to produce anything, for any methods.
Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

start with:

```
rvm reinstall ruby-2.0.0-p247 --disable-binary
rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p247
rvm docs generate
ri GC
```

the initial problem will be handled with https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2118 (thx @a7d7p)

Comment: That didn't work. Issue filed. I'll follow up if something useful comes of it.

Comment: Solved, with the following, thanks to @mpapis:  
    '$ rvm reinstall $ 2.0.0 --disable-binary'
    '$ rvm use 2.0.0'
    '$ rvm docs generate'
    '$ ri GC'